# Hibernate saves additional row instead of updateing and needs two saves

Tags: java, hibernate

Note: for simplyfication i have changed some `variables` names and get rid of unnecessary code to show my issue.

I have two repositories:

```
@Repository
public interface CFolderRepository extends CrudRepository<CFolder, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<CFolder> {}

@Repository
public interface CRepository extends JpaRepository<C, Long>, CFinder, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<C> {}
```

The class `C` is:

```
@FilterDef(name = "INS_COMPANY_FILTER", parameters = {@ParamDef(name = "insCompanies", type = "string")})
@Filter(name = "INS_COMPANY_FILTER", condition = " INS_COMPANY in (:insCompanies) ")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Audited
@AuditOverrides({@AuditOverride(forClass = EntityLog.class),
        @AuditOverride(forClass = MultitenantEntityBase.class)})
@Entity
@Table(name = "INS_C")
@Getter
public class C extends MultitenantEntityBase {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "C_FOLDER_ID")
    private CFolder cFolder;

    public void addFolder(List<String> clsUrl){
        this.cFolder = CFolder.createFolder(clsUrl);
    }
}
```

`CFolder` is:

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Audited
@AuditOverride(forClass = EntityLog.class)
@Entity
@Table(name = "C_FOLDER")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CFolder extends EntityBase {

    @Column(name = "CREATION_FOLDER_DATE_TIME", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime creationFolderDateTime;

    @Column(name = "UPDATED_FOLDER_DATE_TIME")
    private LocalDateTime updatedFolderDateTime;

    @Column(name = "FOLDER_CREATED_BY", nullable = false)
    private String folderCreatedBy;

    @Column(name = "FOLDER_UPDATED_BY")
    private String folderUpdatedBy;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "cFolder", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @NotAudited
    private Set<FolderDocument> folderDocuments = new HashSet<>();

    public static CFolder createFolder(List<String> clsUrl){
        CFolder cFolder = new CFolder(LocalDateTime.now(), null, SecurityHelper.getUsernameOfAuthenticatedUser(), null, new HashSet<>());

        createFolderDocuments(clsUrl, cFolder);
        return cFolder;
    }

    public void updateFolder(List<String> clsUrl){
        this.updatedFolderDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.folderUpdatedBy = SecurityHelper.getUsernameOfAuthenticatedUser();
        this.folderDocuments.clear();
        createFolderDocuments(clsUrl, this);
    }

    private static void createFolderDocuments(List<String> clsUrl, CFolder cFolder) {
        int documentNumber = 0;
        for (String url : clsUrl) {
            documentNumber++;
            cFolder.folderDocuments.add(new FolderDocument(cFolder, documentNumber, url));
        }
    }
}
```

`FolderDocument` is:

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Audited
@AuditOverride(forClass = EntityLog.class)
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOLDER_DOCUMENT")
public class FolderDocument extends EntityBase {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "C_FOLDER_ID", nullable = false)
    private CFolder cFolder;

    @Column(name = "DOCUMENT_NUMBER", nullable = false)
    private int documentNumber;

    @Column(name = "URL", nullable = false)
    private String url;
}
```

And finally we have a `service` in which i use these `entities` and try to save/load them to/from database:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class CFolderService {
    private final CRepository cRepository;
    private final CommunicationClServiceClient communicationServiceClient;
    private final CFolderRepository cFolderRepository;


        public List<ClDocumentDto> getClCaseFolder(Long cId) {

            C insCase = cRepository.findCById(cId);
            List<ClDocumentDto> clDocumentsDto = getClDocuments(insCase.getCNumber()); // here, the object has one cFolder, but many FolderDocument inside of it

            return clDocumentsDto;
        }

    @Transactional
    public void updateCFolder(Long cId) {
        C insC = cRepository.findCById(cId);
        List<ClDocumentDto> clDocumentsDto = getClDocuments(insC.getCNumber());

        List<String> clsUrl = clDocumentsDto.stream().filter(c -> "ACTIVE".equals(c.getCommunicationStatus())).map(ClDocumentDto::getUrl).collect(Collectors.toList());
        if (Objects.isNull(insC.getCFolder())) {
            insC.addFolder(clsUrl); 
        } else {
            insC.getCFolder().updateFolder(clsUrl);
        }
        cFolderRepository.save(insC.getCFolder()); // here it saves additional FolderDocument instead of updateing it
        cRepository.save(insC); // need second save, so can get these collection in getClaimCaseFolder successfully
    }
}
```

I have two issues inside. In the example i was trying to clear the objects that i found from DataBase and create new ones.

1) 
First is that i have to make two `save` operation to successfully restore the object in `getClCaseFolder` method (outside transactional).

2)
Second is that everytime i am saving - i get additional `FolderDocument` object pinned to `CFolder` object inside `C` object. I want to clear this collection and save new one.

I am not sure why `hibernate` does not update this object?

**EDIT:**

I think that i do sth like:
           `cRepository.save(insC);`

instead of `this.folderDocuments.clear();`

i can do:

```
for(Iterator<FolderDocument> featureIterator = this.folderDocuments.iterator();
    featureIterator.hasNext(); ) {
    FolderDocument feature = featureIterator .next();
    feature.setCFolder(null);
    featureIterator.remove();
}
```

But i get `eager` fetching, why lazy wont work? There is an error using it.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are setting `ID` in that `Entity` or not.
If `ID` is present/set in `entity` and that ID  is also present in DB table then hibernate **will update that record**, But if ID is not present/set in Entity object the Hibernate always treat that object as a new record and **add new record to the table** instead of Updating.

Comment: Why do i need to have two saves in example above?

Comment: In the example i was trying to `clear` the objects that i found from DataBase and create new ones.

Comment: yes you can dothat, better you call `cRepository.delete(insC);` then `cRepository.save(insC)` or instard of delete that entity you can update same and call `save()` but dont change ID

Comment: The reason i do not want `update` with the same `ID` is that the collection may differ - and i do not want to match them before/after by its content

Comment: then delete that record  and then add new entry